Terraform help: The parent organizational unit '<OU>' is not enrolled in AWS Control Tower error
I'm trying to import an account that already exists into terraform. I seem to have done so successfully and when I try to create the account it just wants to modify a few attributes in place. However, when I run an apply it errors out with the following:
│ Error: provisioning account  failed: InvalidParametersException  The parent organizational unit '' is not enrolled in AWS Control Tower.
I'm not sure what this means. Does anyone have any suggestions?
I've checked the parent OU and it's all completely find and enrolled. I went to AWS service catalogue, saw the the account was tainted, so I updated the account manually. That seemed to work so I tried another terraform apply but I keep running into the same error. Really stuck with how to solve this. D
The code is relatively simple but I will display it below. All the variables are set normally and work:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    controltower = {
      source  = "idealo/controltower"
      version = "~> 1.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "controltower" {
  region  = "eu-west-2"
  profile = "root"
}

resource "controltower_aws_account" "account" {
  name                = "<name>"
  email               = "<email>" 
  organizational_unit = var.organizational_unit

  sso {
    first_name = var.sso_first_name
    last_name  = var.sso_last_name
    email      = var.sso_email
  }
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      organizational_unit,
      email
    ]
  }
}


Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be great if you could add the code you have to the question.

Hi, Yeah absolutely I've edited the above :)

Oh, ok, so that is not the official AWS provider, right?

No it's not but the link can be found here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/idealo/controltower/latest

Yeah, so I would suggest raising an issue there since it's an unofficial provider.

Already raised the issue, but thought it would be good to post on here to check too.
But I actually managed to find the solution to this. It took me updating the provisioned product in the AWS console on service catalogue. I had to reaffirm that it matched that of the terraform script, despite the fact the state file and the terraform variables were completely congruent. It actually had nothing to do with the parental organization; that was all a red-herring.

Ha, that's interesting. Please post your findings as an answer!

You are probably passing the OU id directly but this is expecting something like:
{   key: "ManagedOrganizationalUnit",   value: "Custom (ou-xfe5-a8hb8ml8)" },

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/controltower/latest/userguide/automated-provisioning-walkthrough.html
